# how to read the path of swf file from MYSQL , then view it on the web

Tags: php, mysql, html

My code below does not work.

`nisreen` is the name of DB , and the table name is `ana`.

What I want is to read the path of the SWF file from the database, then view it  on the web-page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Untitled 1</title>

        <?php

            $con =mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

            mysql_select_db("nisreen", $con);
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ana LIMIT 1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $row['title'];
            }

            echo '</head>';

            echo '<body>';
            echo $row; 
            echo '<object data="'.$row . "'";
            echo "type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='600'  height='600'>";

            echo '</object>';
            echo '
    </body>    
</html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning your fetched data to a variable, $row exists only in the scope of that while loop. try something like

```
<?php

    $con =mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    mysql_select_db("nisreen", $con);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ana LIMIT 1");
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $path = $row['path'];   
         }

echo '</head>';

echo '<body>';
echo $title; 
echo '<object data="'.$path. "'";
echo "type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='600'  height='600'>";

echo '</object>';
echo '
</body>

</html>';
?>
```

Comment: it did not work ?? 
i save the path in the title field .. 
this is the path :E:\graduate  project\DR.flash\int.swf in DB >
but when i run the page it gives me nothing at all

Comment: echo $title;  //this line print the path of SWF file ..but the flash doesn't view on the screen !

Comment: i fixed the wrong by changing the path in MYSQL .. in DB (E://) read it in lower case, so it does't match the specific file !! :(